# What is the basic principles of Kolmogorov complexity?

Tags: compression

I've been researching multiple sources over the last couple days on Kolmogorov complexity and I just can't understand the basic principles. I get that it's the shortest description of that object but I read you can't actually calculate it and that confuses me. so if someone could give me a nice simple explanation of it that would be very helpful.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [softwareengineering.se]

Answer (score 2):

**How would you describe your favorite food to someone?**

You might answer something like "the street tacos from the restaurant on 5th street". But wait, are those the soft shell or hard shell kind? What city is "5th street" in? The tacos they serve now, or the ones they served when they first opened 30 years ago? We can keep asking more and more of these questions forever, and the description of your tacos will always be missing some minor detail.

***It turns out, the only way to describe your favorite food completely is to describe every other aspect of the universe those tacos exist within.***

You're skeptical though - you were able to describe the tacos well enough to have your coworkers order them for you. In fact, sometimes you just texted them the most essential details. "2 5th st tacos plz" was enough, but any less and they'd probably get confused.

***You've compressed the description to it's bare minimum for your coworkers to execute a takeout order.***

That order you texted is like an algorithm, and your coworkers are like a computer. You can imagine that every algorithm has a minimum size that, when fed into a computer, will result in the desired output. The "size" or "length" of that algorithm is its relative Kolmogorov Complexity, and computers are all similar in ways that allow this property to be leveraged.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Uncomputability_of_Kolmogorov_complexity) to have a good example and sketch for a proof.

If you could implement `function KolmogorovComplexity(string s)`, you could use that to write the shown `function GenerateComplexString()`. The program's length is 7001401288 but it produces a string which's "compmlexity" is 8000000000, which contradicts the very definition of Kolmogorov complexity.

Turing's [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) might be easier to understand, although it mentions:

> The undecidability of the halting problem also follows from the fact that Kolmogorov complexity is not computable.